# Unmarshalling $oid and $date json/bson to go

Tags: json, go, bson

I'm trying to unmarshal the following json string in go:

```
{"dt": {"$date": 1422019966844}, "_id": {"$oid": "54c24d7eabb7c06d4f000371"}}
```

I've tried a number of different ways to unmarshal this but couldn't find a way that works. What is the idiomatic way to unmarshal that to an object?

Thanks,
Z.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the format of the JSON you're getting, the best you can do is to design a struct with the same format.

```
type MyJSON struct {
    Dt struct {
        Date int64 `json:"$date"`
    } `json:"dt"`
    Id struct {
        Oid string `json:"$oid"`
    } `json:"_id"`
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/C2Bc7kf0B8

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to unmarshal the JSON to Go:

```
d := []byte(`{"dt": {"$date": 1422019966844}, "_id": {"$oid": "54c24d7eabb7c06d4f000371"}}`)
var v struct {
    Dt struct {
        Date int64 `json:"$date"`
    }
    ID struct {
        OID string `json:"$oid"`
    } `json:"_id"`
}
err := json.Unmarshal(d, &v)
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/wRLfhd2Rrj)

You probably want to unmarshal to something like:

```
 var v struct {
    ID bson.ObjectID `bson:"_id"`
    Dt time.Time
 }
```

I suggest unmarshalling the original BSON instead of the Javascript client's representation of the BSON.

Comment: var v struct {
    ID bson.ObjectID `bson:"_id"`
    Dt time.Time
 } 
is ideally what I'd like to do but is there a way to do it given the json string I'm getting?